# REST - How to pass an array of long in parameter with Jersey?

Tags: java, rest, jax-ws, jersey

I am trying to pass an array of long with Jersey :

In the client side i have trying something like that :

```
@GET
@Consume("text/plain")
@Produces("application/xml)
Response getAllAgentsById(@params("listOfId") List<Long> listOfId);
```

Is there a way to realize something like that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to stick to "application/xml" format and avoid JSON format, you should wrap this data into a JAXB annotated object, so that Jersey can use the built-in [MessageBodyWriter](http://jsr311.java.net/nonav/javadoc/javax/ws/rs/ext/MessageBodyWriter.html) / [MessageBodyReader](http://jsr311.java.net/nonav/javadoc/javax/ws/rs/ext/MessageBodyReader.html).

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public ListOfIds{

 private List<Long> ids;

 public ListOfIds() {}

 public ListOfIds(List<Long> ids) {
  this.ids= ids;
 }

 public List<Long> getIds() {
  return ids; 
 }

}
```

On the client side (using Jersey client)

```
// get your list of Long
List<Long> list = computeListOfIds();

// wrap it in your object
ListOfIds idList = new ListOfIds(list);

Builder builder = webResource.path("/agentsIds/").type("application/xml").accept("application/xml");
ClientResponse response = builder.post(ClientResponse.class, idList);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to pass array of long its possible without any problem. But I will probably pass the long as comma delimited string. (123,233,2344,232) and then split the string and convert in to long.

If not, I suggest you use Json Serialization. If you are using java client, then google gson is a good option. In client side, I will encode my list:

```
  List<Long> test = new ArrayList<Long>();
            for (long i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
             test.add(i);
            }

  String s = new Gson().toJson(test);
```

And pass this string as post param. In the server side, I  will decode like this.

```
 Type collectionType = new TypeToken<List<Long>>() {
        } // end new
                .getType();
        List<Long> longList = new Gson().fromJson(longString,
                collectionType);
```

Comment: May be , I mis-understood your question.( my previous solution will still work). But usually when you want to pass arrays and other complex data strucutures, its better to use some kind of serialization mechanism. I usually use Json format for communication. Let me know, if this is what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's a solution but my list can contains more than 10000 entries. Can i have a problem with your solution?

Comment: 10k entries will be very long string, you may face some problems with that. I think POST method will be better

Comment: Yes, you have to post. What client do you use. If you are using java client, then I suggest you use google gson library. I am adding an answer, since I want to paste some code fragment.

Comment: I used two types of clients, PHP (Zend) and JAVA. Is there a problem with PHP client? If i have understood this code should be works :@POST
@Consumes("application/json")
@Produces("application/xml")
Response getAllAgentsById(@params("listOfId") String listOfId);
and i can use gson. Is it ok? Sorry for my bad english :-)

Comment: You are fine using php. Just find some good json encoder in php for client side.

Comment: In effect Gson is a java framework so i can't use it because my code (in the server side) must not be dependent of the client side! Thanks a lot !

Comment: Can i use Gson on java server side and an other encoder in php for client php side?

Comment: hmm, I do not understand. Are you ok with the solution or do you need more details. You can use any json library in client side.( if you use java client, then I prefer Gson).

Comment: I am ok with your solution! I will use Gson on the server side (and java client side) and zend json on the other client in php. Thanks a lot for your interest in my problem!